# How to set CSS style in Polymer 3 using JS functions

Tags: javascript, css, polymer-3.x

So, I am fairly new to Polymer but I have worked trough all tutorials I could find and the search function doesn't help me with my problem either.

I am trying to set the style of elements via JS functions. I know that I could use things like:

```
getColor () {
  if(this.is_even) {
    return  "background-color: green;";
  }
  else {
    return "background-color: red;";
  }
}

static get template() {
  return html`
    <div class="icon" style$="[[getColor()]]"></div>
  `
}
```

To set my icon's background color depending on its "is_even" property. My question is: Can I do this in css style tags too? Is there an equivilant syntax like this:

```
.icon
{
  $[[getColor()]]
}
```

or maybe

```
.icon
{
  background-color$: [[getColor()]];
}
```

I am trying to edit the style of my ":host" element depending on certain conditions via this kind of syntax and I can't find anything about it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible with plane css. It might be with a css preprocessors language but I haven't looked into this yet. However, the way you are showing in your first code block should be working ?!

Comment: I know that the first example works, I never stated the opposite. I just find a syntax like the second one more appealing and thought that Polymer might have such a feature. An extra preprocessor would be a little too much overhead for my project, I just had the hope that the feature already exists and I just could not find it.

Comment: No unfortunately this isn't possible and I highly doubt that this will be a feature one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample how to do with css :

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cemane?file=index.js)

```
static get template() {
return html`
  <style> 
  .cfalse {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .ctrue {
    background-color: green;
  }
  </style>

  <div class$="icon c[[is_even]]"></div>
`;
}
```

You may do it with observer :

```
static get observers() {
  return [
    'checkColor(is_even)'
  ]
}

checkColor(e) {
  this.set('getColor', !!e ? "background-color: green;" : "background-color: red;" );

  }

static get template() {
  return html`
    <div class="icon" style$="[[getColor]]"></div>` }
```

Or you may set observer at property decleration :

```
static get properties() {
    return {
      is_even: {
        type: Boolean,
        // Observer method identified by name
        observer: 'checkColor'
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT : Also it is possible to render the html style with Polymer Lit Element's advantage. In order to use lit element

```
import { LitElement, html } from '@polymer/lit-element';
```

then after extend your custom element lit Element's class :

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties(){.....
 ....
```

Then finally:

```
${this.is_even?
  html`<div class="icon" style="background-color: green;"></div>`:
  html`<div class="icon" style="background-color: red;"></div>`}
```

For more about [litElement](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/try/expressions)

Comment: Thank you for your very elaborate example. I think I will stick to the observer-based solution since my project already relies on a lot of these. I haven't yet looked into LitElement and I don't think I will do for this project, but I will definitely check it out before I start my next one.